# How can I store shared Location from Google Maps to a TextView/String?

Tags: android, gps, location, maps, share

Currently creating an app that creates event for Sport matches - time, day, location etc.. I have a button that open Google Maps and added the "android.intent.action.SEND" that I may be able to share the location from Maps to my App, however I do not know exactly how to pull the long/lat OR the url from Maps and store it in a String or TextView/EditText. 
How can I do this?

I've created TextView, EditTexts, and variables. Sharing to my app just resets it.

```
//From Manifest
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"></action>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>

//Button to Open Google Maps

locationPicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=");
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    PackageManager managerclock = getPackageManager();
    i = managerclock.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    startActivity(i);
   }
});
```

When shared from Google Maps, the url or longitude/latitude will be stored in a variable or set as a TextView that I may share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no classic way of getting a location via `intent` from Google Maps (as getting a picture from camera, for example).

The [Google Maps Place Picker API](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/placepicker) could have solved this for you, but it is now **depcrecated**. It will be disabled on July 29th, 2019 for some reason.

You have to choose a different `Google Maps API` for this task. Google has made an [API Picker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/api-picker) to help you pick your desired one. Have a look at it.

I'm afraid you'll have to re-design the way of how users choose location in your app. One way is to create an activity with a Google Map inside it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The Maps Place Picker API seemed like the almost perfect solution, unfortunately deprecated. 
I've tried using the Google Maps API but for a reason I'm unaware of the API key didn't work for me, so this was my work around. I'll look into the API Picker though.

Comment: You're welcome :) the implementation of the API key is tricky at first, there are a lot of things to consider, so carefully follow their documentation. Please feel free to accept my answer If you think it helped you.